# How do you compile a template in a directive before sending it to the DOM?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <my-template src="https://plnkr.co/img/plunker.png"></my-template>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
myApp.directive('myTemplate', function() {
  return {
    scope: {src: '@'},
    template: '<img src="{{src}}"></img>'
  }
});
```

In my example [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ChpDyRNmdPtfXGkdHZM), I have an image that is loaded dynamically from a directive template.  If you look at the console when you run, you can see an error trying to load "https://run.plnkr.co/xLToRcEuT2Xr8he7/%7B%7Bsrc%7D%7D", which is the unresolved version of the template (%7B%7Vsrc%7D%7D = {{src}}). This is then picked up by angular as a binding and the correct img is loaded.

The code works, but I don't like having errors lying around. I also don't need the bindings in the template hanging around once it's been resolved in the directive, as there is already a binding on the parent element and the underlying children will never change independently.

Is there a way to compile the template before sending it back to the DOM to a) remove the bindings and (primarily) b) avoid this error.

Comment: I didn't see any console-errors. Have you tried <img ng-src={{src}}">?  ng-src instead of src

Comment: Interestingly I just checked (on a different computer) and I'm not seeing the console-errors any more in that plnkr.  However, I just reproduced it in a much simpler way without even having a directive: <img ng-init="src = 'https://plnkr.co/img/plunker.png'" src="{{src}}">.  ng-src fixed it, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `{{src}}` to bind once only, prefix it with a double colon ie `{{src}}` becomes `{{::src}}`. Also, add `ng-src` instead of `src` to the image ie `<img ng-src={{::src}} />`

Comment: Presumably this removes the binding after resolution, using up less resources? ng-src fixed the error, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it means its not imcluded in future `$digest` cycles hence using fewer resources.